# PHP login form within Bootstrap modal not working

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a login form within a Bootstrap modal but when the correct information is entered the user is shown the same page but with the modal closed i.e. not redirected to `viewDashboard.php`.

**Code**

```
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="Modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="ModalLabel">Login to Portal</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post">
            <fieldset>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputID" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Username</label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputID" name="user" placeholder="Username">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputPassword" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Password</label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
              </div>
            </fieldset>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php

    include("core/connection.php");

    if($conn AND !empty($_POST)){

    $stid = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Customers.CustomerNo = ".$_POST['user']."");
    oci_execute($stid);

    $count = oci_fetch_all($stid, $res);
    if ($count > 0) { 

      session_start();
      $_SESSION['account'] = $_POST['account'];
      header("Location: viewDashboard.php"); 

    }

    oci_free_statement($stid);
    oci_close($conn);

    }

    ?>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your user is correctly authenticated you should create a new `session` for him

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['user'] = array('id' => '...', name => '...', ...);
```

The information in the session can then be used in your secured section to check if the user is connected

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['user']) {
    // redirect to login page
}
```

Finally the redirection should be made before any information is sent to the client using:

```
// once logged
header('location:viewDashboard.php');

// on logout or if trying to access secured section
header('location:login.php');
```

**EDIT to reflect the first 2 comments :**

Your page should be structured like this:

```
//login.php
<?php
if (isset($_POST)) {
    // login check
    if ($isLogged) {
        // session creation
        header('location:...');
    }
}
?>
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
    ...
    <!-- Your modal box -->
    </body>
</html>
```

If you want to re-open your modal box upon unsuccessful login, you should use your PHP to set the value of a flag (like `!$isLogged` you set a flag in your JS). If the flag is set to true, you trigger the modal box with Twitter's boostrap js.

References :

1. [Sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)
2. [Headers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That is basically what I am already doing though. The problem is that once a user does log in, he sees the home page without the modal i.e. not `viewDashboard.php`.

Comment: You try to do your redirection in your HTML body, you can't do that, it must be done before any content is sent to the client

Comment: So move the PHP to the top?